# how to create 50% line?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i downloaded this python code from gitHUB , i am trying to add a  50% line that will mark the 50% price level, 
the code takes 12 values of the CSV file and plot them with a simple moving average  , then moves to the next 12 price value .

example :- if the high of the 12 candles was 60 and the low was 58.20 the line should be @  59.10
            (high + low ) * .50 .
i am very new to coding , any help will be much appreciated .
[like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC9iv.jpg)

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_finance
import numpy as np
import uuid


# Input your csv file here with historical data

ad = genfromtxt('../inpredo-master/eurusd.csv', delimiter=',' ,dtype=str)
pd = np.flipud(ad)

buy_dir = '../inpredo-master/data/train/buy/'
sell_dir = '../inpredo-master/data/train/sell/'

def convolve_sma(array, period):
    return np.convolve(array, np.ones((period,))/period, mode='valid')

def graphwerk(start, finish):
    open = []
    high = []
    low = []
    close = []
    volume = []
    date = []
    for x in range(finish-start):



# Below filtering is valid for eurusd.csv file. Other financial data files have different orders so you need to find out
# what means open, high and close in their respective order.

        open.append(float(pd[start][1]))
        high.append(float(pd[start][2]))
        low.append(float(pd[start][3]))
        close.append(float(pd[start][4]))
        volume.append(float(pd[start][5]))
        date.append(pd[start][0])
        start = start + 1

    close_next = float(pd[finish][4])

    sma = convolve_sma(close, 5)
    smb = list(sma)
    diff = sma[-1] - sma[-2]

    for x in range(len(close)-len(smb)):
        smb.append(smb[-1]+diff)

    fig = plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(3, 3), dpi=50, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    dx = fig.add_subplot(111)
    #mpl_finance.volume_overlay(ax, open, close, volume, width=0.4, colorup='b', colordown='b', alpha=1)
    mpl_finance.candlestick2_ochl(dx,open, close, high, low, width=1.5, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.5)

    plt.autoscale()
    plt.plot(smb, color="blue", linewidth=10, alpha=0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
    comp_ratio = close_next / close[-1]
    print(comp_ratio)

    if close[-1] > close_next:
            print('close value is bigger')
            print('last value: ' + str(close[-1]))
            print('next value: ' + str(close_next))
            print('sell')
            plt.savefig(sell_dir + str(uuid.uuid4()) +'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
    else:
            print('close value is smaller')
            print('last value: '+ str(close[-1]))
            print('next value: ' + str(close_next))
            print('buy')
            plt.savefig(buy_dir + str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')


    #plt.show()
    open.clear()
    close.clear()
    volume.clear()
    high.clear()
    low.clear()
    plt.cla()
    plt.clf()


iter_count = int(len(pd)/4)
print(iter_count)
iter = 0


for x in range(len(pd)-4):
   graphwerk(iter, iter+12)
   iter = iter + 2
```

```
csv file
01.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.26670,1.26755,1.26530,1.26630,10415099609.375
01.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.26625,1.26670,1.26205,1.26585,14760500000
01.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.26585,1.26735,1.26525,1.26620,13230599609.375
01.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.26620,1.26725,1.26565,1.26645,6018500000
01.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.26645,1.26915,1.26595,1.26815,10081700195.3125
01.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.26815,1.26940,1.26695,1.26923,10532099609.375
01.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.26940,1.27000,1.26680,1.26750,20681099609.375
01.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.26740,1.27035,1.26545,1.26835,45380101562.5
01.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.26840,1.26980,1.26250,1.26745,64015437500
01.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.26745,1.26850,1.26335,1.26640,46933960937.5
01.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.26635,1.26675,1.26360,1.26505,49354550781.25
01.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.26510,1.26750,1.26490,1.26690,38353980468.75
01.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.26690,1.26780,1.26100,1.26335,51726113281.25
01.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.26335,1.26410,1.25820,1.26065,48427261718.75
01.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.26065,1.26385,1.26010,1.26265,58267585937.5
01.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.26275,1.26500,1.25885,1.25950,64386898437.5
01.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.25950,1.26405,1.25945,1.26315,48192398437.5
01.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.26330,1.26570,1.26170,1.26245,33415000000
01.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.26245,1.26680,1.26240,1.26655,21942000000
01.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.26655,1.26900,1.26240,1.26725,31800599609.375
01.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.26720,1.26725,1.25890,1.25910,28712099609.375
01.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.25915,1.26355,1.25915,1.26090,13886115234.375
01.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.26095,1.26330,1.26050,1.26160,7700399902.3438
01.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.26150,1.26155,1.25810,1.25960,9857299804.6875
02.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.25960,1.26320,1.25900,1.26145,14374099609.375
02.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.26150,1.26460,1.25960,1.26365,13274799804.6875
02.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.26365,1.26445,1.26255,1.26310,14129099609.375
02.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.26310,1.26400,1.26180,1.26205,9293599609.375
02.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.26205,1.26480,1.26170,1.26475,11337700195.3125
02.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.26470,1.26510,1.25995,1.25995,18697300781.25
02.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.25995,1.26360,1.25995,1.26115,19145199218.75
02.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.26115,1.26385,1.26085,1.26185,19929699218.75
02.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.26170,1.26275,1.25620,1.25750,49809378906.25
02.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.25750,1.26335,1.25740,1.26310,40306300781.25
02.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.26305,1.26815,1.26275,1.26425,40871003906.25
02.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.26420,1.26515,1.26200,1.26435,37048898437.5
02.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.26430,1.27060,1.26355,1.27050,47789347656.25
02.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.27050,1.27410,1.26790,1.27025,57312585937.5
02.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.27030,1.27435,1.26740,1.27255,72631250000
02.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.27260,1.27655,1.27100,1.27170,55846753906.25
02.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.27170,1.27285,1.26840,1.27225,43732121093.75
02.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.27225,1.27370,1.27070,1.27175,32379400390.625
02.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.27175,1.27175,1.26950,1.27085,32533900390.625
02.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.27085,1.27160,1.26655,1.26965,32732099609.375
02.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.26965,1.27185,1.26820,1.27060,37340800781.25
02.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.27045,1.27280,1.27030,1.27125,13365099609.375
02.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.27125,1.27225,1.27065,1.27209,3485399902.3438
02.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.27214,1.27225,1.26955,1.27080,7589700195.3125
03.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.27085,1.27095,1.26825,1.26845,9040200195.3125
03.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.26850,1.27125,1.26820,1.26995,9080400390.625
03.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.27005,1.27280,1.26995,1.27220,12558700195.3125
03.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.27215,1.27415,1.27100,1.27315,15529500000
03.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.27315,1.27335,1.26835,1.26995,22322699218.75
03.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.27000,1.27100,1.26905,1.27055,11171400390.625
03.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.27055,1.27285,1.26710,1.26815,24364199218.75
03.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.26815,1.27085,1.26785,1.26965,33773031250
03.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.26965,1.27030,1.26345,1.26385,65365960937.5
03.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.26390,1.26475,1.26065,1.26240,70053898437.5
03.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.26240,1.26480,1.26175,1.26455,55102738281.25
03.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.26450,1.26615,1.26305,1.26390,55239898437.5
03.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.26400,1.26560,1.26170,1.26220,61085898437.5
03.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.26220,1.26440,1.26020,1.26305,66087703125
03.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.26310,1.26535,1.26160,1.26260,52164250000
03.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.26260,1.26920,1.26130,1.26920,63437726562.5
03.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.26915,1.26920,1.26565,1.26690,55412011718.75
03.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.26695,1.26820,1.26330,1.26645,36716898437.5
03.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.26645,1.26715,1.26460,1.26555,26533900390.625
03.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.26560,1.26825,1.26530,1.26545,28182000000
03.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.26545,1.27105,1.26455,1.27105,23903400390.625
03.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.27105,1.27185,1.26965,1.27160,14712500000
03.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.27155,1.27270,1.27102,1.27130,5629799804.6875
03.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.27135,1.27215,1.27018,1.27040,6461899902.3438
04.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.27040,1.27105,1.26775,1.26835,10025500000
04.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.26830,1.27120,1.26775,1.27115,11039500000
04.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.27115,1.27165,1.26975,1.27155,10000000000
04.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.27170,1.27180,1.27000,1.27095,10793000000
04.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.27092,1.27123,1.26655,1.26717,34227898437.5
04.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.26706,1.26855,1.26562,1.26815,22185900390.625
04.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.26815,1.26905,1.26635,1.26715,18529199218.75
04.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.26715,1.26815,1.26460,1.26535,31622500000
04.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.26535,1.26640,1.25910,1.25945,71048890625
04.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.25935,1.26135,1.25490,1.26050,66295320312.5
04.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.26050,1.26122,1.25850,1.25952,56125160156.25
04.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.25963,1.26435,1.25945,1.26235,52437210937.5
04.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.26230,1.26555,1.26135,1.26315,50761191406.25
04.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.26310,1.26400,1.26005,1.26165,54053160156.25
04.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.26165,1.27015,1.26130,1.26915,69188601562.5
04.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.26910,1.27415,1.26700,1.27380,76136000000
04.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.27380,1.28475,1.27180,1.28380,67410257812.5
04.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.28380,1.28400,1.27860,1.27920,31272300781.25
04.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.27915,1.28270,1.27860,1.28225,20295199218.75
04.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.28225,1.28250,1.27825,1.27930,25373000000
04.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.27930,1.27940,1.27475,1.27895,27802800781.25
04.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.27900,1.27945,1.27690,1.27760,13797299804.6875
04.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.27750,1.27900,1.27450,1.27710,8987030273.4375
04.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.27710,1.27745,1.27590,1.27730,5301500000
05.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.27725,1.27795,1.27345,1.27385,9740400390.625
05.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.27390,1.27605,1.27315,1.27565,8939200195.3125
05.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.27570,1.27625,1.27470,1.27575,6643500000
05.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.27575,1.27745,1.27555,1.27670,4625000000
05.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.27670,1.27675,1.27370,1.27460,6305700195.3125
05.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.27465,1.27645,1.27460,1.27535,6466899902.3438
05.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.27535,1.27835,1.27430,1.27790,14984599609.375
05.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.27790,1.27910,1.27640,1.27655,37232199218.75
05.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.27650,1.27795,1.27490,1.27760,69940601562.5
05.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.27745,1.27990,1.27465,1.27585,48363160156.25
05.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.27585,1.27825,1.27160,1.27230,50225050781.25
05.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.27230,1.27245,1.26765,1.26870,56966554687.5
05.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.26870,1.26995,1.26765,1.26855,57704800781.25
05.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.26850,1.27475,1.26270,1.26660,73293859375
05.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.26665,1.27110,1.26510,1.26805,63439039062.5
05.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.26805,1.26915,1.26500,1.26760,46485898437.5
05.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.26760,1.26760,1.26305,1.26530,40705488281.25
05.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.26530,1.26735,1.26395,1.26510,24142800781.25
05.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.26515,1.26765,1.26395,1.26405,20044240234.375
05.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.26410,1.27185,1.26390,1.26895,24642150390.625
05.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.26895,1.27270,1.26755,1.27145,25435199218.75
05.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.27145,1.27395,1.27123,1.27198,9938599609.375
07.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.27254,1.27340,1.27215,1.27225,3177699951.1719
07.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.27220,1.27290,1.27155,1.27290,3124000000
08.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.27290,1.27630,1.27265,1.27610,4889299804.6875
08.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.27610,1.27715,1.27525,1.27540,10667599609.375
08.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.27540,1.27670,1.27395,1.27670,6644100097.6563
08.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.27670,1.27850,1.27550,1.27720,10169900390.625
08.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.27710,1.27770,1.27530,1.27585,10640799804.6875
08.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.27585,1.27780,1.27450,1.27690,13974000000
08.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.27690,1.28290,1.27690,1.28150,30321500000
08.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.28150,1.28825,1.28075,1.28715,49120078125
08.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.28715,1.28990,1.28695,1.28965,56241667968.75
08.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.28965,1.29150,1.28785,1.28900,45953101562.5
08.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.28890,1.29030,1.28655,1.28720,43155812500
08.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.28715,1.28810,1.28650,1.28660,34700199218.75
08.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.28660,1.28750,1.28430,1.28500,44295500000
08.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.28500,1.29000,1.28405,1.28980,64781000000
08.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.28975,1.29140,1.28740,1.28920,59691851562.5
08.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.28930,1.29485,1.28870,1.29275,82100601562.5
08.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.29275,1.29535,1.29070,1.29415,74101398437.5
08.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.29425,1.29465,1.29080,1.29165,36847250000
08.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.29170,1.29290,1.28945,1.29145,47565800781.25
08.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.29150,1.29570,1.29115,1.29530,27686800781.25
08.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.29530,1.29640,1.29170,1.29405,26914400390.625
08.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.29405,1.29675,1.29330,1.29615,16436599609.375
08.12.2008 22:00:00.000,1.29620,1.29620,1.29270,1.29360,8185000000
08.12.2008 23:00:00.000,1.29360,1.29375,1.29125,1.29125,6652799804.6875
09.12.2008 00:00:00.000,1.29125,1.29310,1.29060,1.29110,12752400390.625
09.12.2008 01:00:00.000,1.29110,1.29190,1.28580,1.28650,20463500000
09.12.2008 02:00:00.000,1.28650,1.28830,1.28630,1.28710,17926000000
09.12.2008 03:00:00.000,1.28710,1.28840,1.28565,1.28695,12187299804.6875
09.12.2008 04:00:00.000,1.28695,1.28855,1.28685,1.28725,13874200195.3125
09.12.2008 05:00:00.000,1.28720,1.28890,1.28625,1.28870,23636500000
09.12.2008 06:00:00.000,1.28880,1.28890,1.28685,1.28745,21487099609.375
09.12.2008 07:00:00.000,1.28740,1.28780,1.28420,1.28680,64233000000
09.12.2008 08:00:00.000,1.28690,1.28695,1.28280,1.28540,87313210937.5
09.12.2008 09:00:00.000,1.28540,1.28890,1.28540,1.28635,73916296875
09.12.2008 10:00:00.000,1.28622,1.28930,1.28615,1.28730,52849898437.5
09.12.2008 11:00:00.000,1.28735,1.28755,1.28125,1.28380,53706824218.75
09.12.2008 12:00:00.000,1.28380,1.28735,1.28355,1.28630,49799679687.5
09.12.2008 13:00:00.000,1.28625,1.28625,1.27980,1.28270,63262031250
09.12.2008 14:00:00.000,1.28275,1.28540,1.28145,1.28418,70842398437.5
09.12.2008 15:00:00.000,1.28423,1.29165,1.28410,1.28940,79257851562.5
09.12.2008 16:00:00.000,1.28940,1.29540,1.28930,1.29360,60811527343.75
09.12.2008 17:00:00.000,1.29360,1.30005,1.29330,1.29730,47695859375
09.12.2008 18:00:00.000,1.29730,1.29770,1.29130,1.29300,30233500000
09.12.2008 19:00:00.000,1.29300,1.29370,1.28875,1.29175,23517789062.5
09.12.2008 20:00:00.000,1.29180,1.29355,1.29060,1.29265,23500177734.375
09.12.2008 21:00:00.000,1.29275,1.29290,1.29060,1.29255,12979599609.375
```

Comment: Can you also paste the link to download the csv file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) to draw a horizontal line in matplotlib.

For example:

```
plt.axhline((max(list_of_values) + min(list_of_values)) / 2)
```